# Verify $\left (x^2-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^2} \right )xe^{-x^2/2}=3xe^{-x^2/2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider partial differential equation:

$$u_t(x,t)=\left (x^2-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}  \right )u(x,t)$$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$ with boundary condition $u(x,0)=xe^{-x^2/2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I need to verify that:

$$\left (x^2-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}  \right )xe^{-x^2/2}=3xe^{-x^2/2}$$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

What should I do?

And, how can I determine a solution to the pde by using the property that this equality holds?

Comment: The left hand side is $x^2(xe^{-x^2/2})-\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(xe^{-x^2/2})$. Just evaluate the derivatives and check equality with the right hand side.

Comment: @MattDickau How can I determine a solution to pde by using property that equality holds?

Comment: @Melina : as per your question, you are only asked to *verify* the given solution. Nothing there on how to get to that solution nor if it is the only solution and what might be other solutions. So only-thing left is to compute and check.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I meant in comment that since that property (that I asked to verify) holds by using it to determine a solution to pde

Comment: @Melina don't know if I'm plain stupid right now or if your question is really not clear. You can verify $\left (x^2-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}  \right )xe^{-x^2/2}=3xe^{-x^2/2}$, can you? Or is this not the (main) problem?

Comment: @GyroGearloose That was easy I just showed but then I asked Matt how can I determine a solution of pdf by using that fact(property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify $$\left (x^2-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}  \right )xe^{-x^2/2}=3xe^{-x^2/2}$$ note that the left hand side is $x^2(xe^{-x^2/2})-\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(xe^{-x^2/2})$. Just evaluate the derivatives and check equality with the right hand side, and you can see that it holds.

To use this fact to find a solution to the PDE
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u(x,t)=\left (x^2-\frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}  \right )u(x,t)$$
$$u(x,0)=xe^{-x^2/2}$$
you can use separation of variables. Assume $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ is the product of two functions, one of $x$ and one of $t$. Then the PDE becomes
$$X(x)T'(t)=(x^2X(x)-X''(x))T(t)$$
which may be rearranged to
$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{x^2X(x)-X''(x)}{X(x)}=k$$
where, since the LHS depends only on $t$ and is equal to the RHS which depends only on $x$, they must both be equal to a constant, $k$.

The initial condition becomes
$$X(x)T(0)=xe^{-x^2/2}$$
Which immediately tells us that we can choose $X(x)=xe^{-x^2/2}$ and $T(0)=1$.

The equality we verified at the start tells us that
$$\frac{x^2X(x)-X''(x)}{X(x)}=\frac{3xe^{-x^2/2}}{xe^{-x^2/2}}=3$$
so that $k=3$ and $T'(t)=3T(t)$. The solution for this, with $T(0)=1$, is $T(t)=e^{3t}$.

Therefore,
$$u(x,t)=xe^{3t-x^2/2}$$